# Spring Integration - is it possible to give encrypted password in imap-idle-channel-adapter?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using the following configuration to read emails using spring integration and imap.

```
<mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                              store-uri="imaps://username:password@mydomain:993/inbox"                                    
                              channel="recieveEmailChannel"
                              should-delete-messages="false"
                              auto-startup="true"
                              java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties" />
```

**Question**

Here the username and password are clear text , but for security reason I need to give either encrypted one or store the username and password in the properties file. Is there any option available do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jasypt to encrypt property values loaded from `*.properties` files:

```
 <mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter 
     store-uri="imaps://${username}:${password}@mydomain:993/inbox" ...
```

More examples are available here: http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html

**UPDATE**: It also works with Spring 2.x: http://www.jasypt.org/spring2.html

Comment: My current spring version is 2.5.6, which I cannot upgrade. Does this works for 2.5.6? if not do I have any other options?